# How to write such a Neo4j query

Tags: neo4j

1. Suppose I have n persons, and m houses. m is far greater than n .I have the relationships

   stored in Neo4j. Each person can have any number of associated houses.  Now, I want a query which will fetch the info like this.

   **person-- and its associated houses** .

Please let me know , how to write a query for this.

Comment: What have you tried? According to the StackOverflow [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), you shouldn't ask a question that you haven't at least tried to find an answer for (and from your question, you haven't shown anything you've done so far). Also: From your question, it's not clear how you're trying to set up the query: API call? Cypher? Please edit your question accordingly. And also please spend the time to properly format it (get rid of the numbered paragraph, and properly format the code-looking part).

Comment: I was trying to look at FOREACH etc, loaded with information, so thought of using stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using cypher:

```
 Match (n:Person)-[:OWNS]->(m:House)
 Return n, collect(m)
```

This assumes you label the type of relationship as person OWNS a House.  This will return the house nodes as an associated array to each person

Comment: +1 for taking the time to answer a poorly asked question. (However, relationships have types, not labels.)

Comment: Semantics. You are labeling a relationship as a type. I wrote the sentence the way I did for brevity.